# How to save a fingerprint directly in the database using ZKFinger SDK-v5.3.0.21-Lite

Tags: c#, sdk, fingerprint

i want save finger print to database  i have this error :

pTemplate.Serialize(fingerprintData);
Error   CS1061  'object' does not contain a definition for 'Serialize' and no extension method 'Serialize' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
 private void axZKFPEngX1_OnEnroll(object sender, AxZKFPEngXControl.IZKFPEngXEvents_OnEnrollEvent e)
    {
        if (!e.actionResult)                
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Register Failed!", "error!");
        }
        else
        {
            sRegTemplate = axZKFPEngX1.GetTemplateAsStringEx("9");
            sRegTemplate10 = axZKFPEngX1.GetTemplateAsStringEx("10");


            if (sRegTemplate.Length > 0)
            {
                if (sRegTemplate10.Length > 0)
                {

                    axZKFPEngX1.AddRegTemplateStrToFPCacheDBEx(fpcHandle, FPID, sRegTemplate, sRegTemplate10);




                }

                else
                    MessageBox.Show("Register 10.0 failed, template length is zero", "error!");

                object pTemplate;
                if (rdb9.Checked)
                {
                    pTemplate = axZKFPEngX1.DecodeTemplate1(sRegTemplate);
                    // Note: 10.0Template can not be compressed (±»ر¹ثُ)
                    axZKFPEngX1.SetTemplateLen(ref pTemplate, 602);
                }
                else
                {
                    pTemplate = axZKFPEngX1.DecodeTemplate1(sRegTemplate10);
                }
                axZKFPEngX1.SaveTemplate("fingerprint.tpl", pTemplate);


                FPID++;
                MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(pTemplate));

                MemoryStream fingerprintData = new MemoryStream();
                pTemplate.Serialize(fingerprintData);
                fingerprintData.Position = 0;
                BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fingerprintData);
                Byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fingerprintData.Length);


                ChkOpenCurrDB();
                MyCmd = Conn.CreateCommand();
                MyCmd.CommandText = "insert into Patient(PatientNum,PatientName,PatientFing,FPID,fpcHandle,sRegTemplate,sRegTemplate10) " +
                " Values('" + PatientNum.Text.Trim() + "','" + Convert.ToString(PatientName.Text) + "',@bytes," +
                " '" + Convert.ToString(FPID) + "','" + Convert.ToString(fpcHandle) + "','" + Convert.ToString(sRegTemplate) + "','" + Convert.ToString(sRegTemplate10) + "')";
                MyCmd.Parameters.Add("FINGERPRINT", SqlDbType.Image).Value = bytes;


                MyCmd.Connection = Conn;
                MyCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


                MessageBox.Show("Record Added/لقد تـم اضـافـة البيانات", "");

                MessageBox.Show("Register Succeed", "Information!");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Register Failed, template length is zero", "error!");
            };
        }            
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Object is a generic datatype which c# provides to store an object of any class. So from the object you cannot get the Serialize method. Use BinaryFormatter for template serialization as you have BinaryReader and MemoryStream.